# Table simulation in R

Tags: simulation

Apologies for the likely simple question.

I know these sorts of questions are asked a lot, but I am struggling with the need to have a table where repeats are allowed in one column, but not in another.

I am looking at simulating a data set of people invited to join a club and then the uptake of them responding to event invitations. I would like n = 1,000 of unique CustomerId variables. They can only join once but be invited to events multiple times, even before the date they join. So, no repeats are allowed on a `CustomerId` `JoinDate` but repeats allowed on their `InvitationDate`.

There should be a column with the outcome of their response to the invitation to the events. These will have a probability of accepting, status 1 of 10% or declining, status 2 of 90%.

Something like the table below:

```
  JoinDate   CustomerId InvitationDate status
   <date>          <dbl> <date>          <dbl>
 1 2022-02-27         25 2022-10-27          1
 2 2022-05-05         36 2022-11-16          1
 3 2022-01-05         70 2022-08-11          1
 4 2022-12-24          7 2022-07-25          1
 5 2022-07-25         24 2022-06-05          1
 6 2022-02-07         81 2022-04-27          1
 7 2022-05-08         80 2022-10-06          2
 8 2022-03-20         91 2022-11-18          2
 9 2022-01-30         57 2022-10-08          2
10 2022-10-24         41 2022-02-07          2
```

I suspect this could be done by creating a starting table of just the dates that the `customerId` has joined and then merging (on `CustomerId`) and stacking a series of event Invitation tables that are created individually. However, I would like to know if there is an elegant solution for this.